# Google Chrome doesn't work

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

I have installed Google Chrome on my Ubuntu 18.04 and I can't reach any web site. It keeps loading without reaching the websites.

I have installed Firefox, and it does work.

Is it a known issue with Google Chrome?

Comment: No, it's not a known issue. Please edit your post to provide the output of `apt policy google-chrome-stable`.

Comment: What method did you use to install Chrome?